# Proving that if a function lies within an integral domain, it satisfies the remainder and the root factor theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, analytic-number-theory

Remainder theorem states that for a $c$ in $F$ and $f(x)$ in $F(x)$. When we divide $f(x)$ by $x - c$ then the remainder is $f(c)$.

the Root Factor Theorem states that for $c$ in $F$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $F(x)$ if $f(c) = 0 $

Now my question is to show that the two above statements would be valid even when the coefficients of $f(x)$ lie in an integral domain $R$. But the following may not hold.

Given nonzero polynomials $f(x), g(x)$ in $F(x)$, let $$S = \{h(x) \in F(x) : h(x) = a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x),\; a(x),b(x) \in F(x)\}$$ then there is a polynomial $d(x)$ in $S$ of smallest degree, and every $h(x)$ in $S$ is divisible by $d(x)$.  (the hint given )

Please let me know if you have a way of proving this, I don't know how to approach it. What I tried to do is mimic the division algorithm.

Thank you,
Samir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to notice is that in an integral domain, if the divisor polynomial is *monic*, then the division algorithm works in just the same way it does for a field (and by the same proof). Therefore your two facts above are valid in any integral domain. Your statement "Given nonzero polynomials..." is false, though: Look at the polynomials $2$ and $x$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$. The lowest-degree linear combinations of these two polynomials is are the even constants, but $x$ is not a multiple of any of them.